# R H2O grid search: how to train top model on new data?

Tags: r, h2o

After running a hyperparameter search and extracting the best model from the grid, is it possible to use the model object to train on a new data set? The only way I see now is to manually create a call to a train function (e.g. h2o.gbm()) with the parameters from the best model, but this is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkpoint` parameter may meet your needs, which trains model further from original model.

This functionality is available for `gbm`,`random forest` and `deep learning` in `h2o` package.

Example code below copying from: http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/master/3689/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/checkpoint.html

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# import the cars dataset:
# this dataset is used to classify whether or not a car is economical based on
# the car's displacement, power, weight, and acceleration, and the year it was made
cars <- h2o.importFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/junit/cars_20mpg.csv")

# convert response column to a factor
cars["economy_20mpg"] <- as.factor(cars["economy_20mpg"])

# set the predictor names and the response column name
predictors <- c("displacement","power","weight","acceleration","year")
response <- "economy_20mpg"

# split into train and validation sets
cars.split <- h2o.splitFrame(data = cars,ratios = 0.8, seed = 1234)
train <- cars.split[[1]]
valid <- cars.split[[2]]

# build a GBM with 1 tree (ntrees = 1) for the first model:
cars_gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train,
                    validation_frame = valid, ntrees = 1, seed = 1234)

# print the auc for the validation data
print(h2o.auc(cars_gbm, valid = TRUE))

# re-start the training process on a saved GBM model using the ‘checkpoint‘ argument:
# the checkpoint argument requires the model id of the model on which you wish to continue building
# get the model's id from "cars_gbm" model using `cars_gbm@model_id`
# the first model has 1 tree, let's continue building the GBM with an additional 49 more trees, so set ntrees = 50

# to see how many trees the original model built you can look at the `ntrees` attribute
print(paste("Number of trees built for cars_gbm model:", cars_gbm@allparameters$ntrees))

# build and train model with 49 additional trees for a total of 50 trees:
cars_gbm_continued <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train,
                    validation_frame = valid, checkpoint = cars_gbm@model_id, ntrees = 50, seed = 1234)

# print the auc for the validation data
print(h2o.auc(cars_gbm_continued, valid = TRUE))

# you can also use checkpointing to pass in a new dataset (see options above for parameters you cannot change)
# simply change out the training and validation frames with your new dataset
```

#### Edit (Based on @Edward's comment below:)

`h2o.grid` will return a series of models, and you can get the best model handel.  All the parameters are saved in the model handel, then you can apply the parameters to new model.

```
grid <- h2o.getGrid(h2o.grid@grid_id,sort_by = "auc",decreasing=TRUE)
model.h2o <- h2o.getModel(grid@model_ids[[1]])
```

`model@allparameters` includes all parameters used, and you can use those to create a new model and new data.

Comment: Yes, I know about checkpoints, but was hoping there was another way to extract the model parameters and train on a completely new data set. Essentially I'd just like to establish a model structure based on some data set and then apply it to different sets. So, for example, after running a GBM grid search I could get an object "best_gbm_params" and do something like h2o.gbm(x, y, train, valid, best_gbm_params, ...) later. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Edward, updated answer based on your given scenario.

Comment: This is what I've been doing in the past, training a grid, then getting the parameters from @allparameters and manually creating a call to h2o.gbm(). What I'd like to do is something like h2o.gbm(training_frame = new_train_data, best_model@allparameters), or have some other way of automatically extracting all parameters from the best model and generating a new call to one of the h2o train functions. I don't like the manual approach because it is tedious, but also because some parameters may be changed or added in the future, imposing a maintenance overhead.

Comment: @Edward, I see you point now.  This would need h2o to add a function to output and models to accept those best estimated parameters.  Another way is to write a function to: base on `args` output from `h2o` training model, then constructing character expression (by matching parameters).  Using `do.call` to run this expression.  This way you don't need to worry about change of parameters, but creating function is still needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, this sounds like a reasonable solution considering there is no native support in H2O for such functionality.